# How to apply a formatter in nested translations with i18next

Tags: translation, i18next

I would like to format nested translations with i18next

Given the resources:

```json
{
  translation: {
    en: {
      food: 'bread',
      food_is_good: "$t(food), that's not bad",
    },
  },
}
```

and a formatting function:

```js
function format(value, format, lng) {
  if (value == undefined) return value;
  switch (format) {
    case 'capitalize':
      return _.capitalize(value);
    default:
      return value;
  }
}
```

that is used in the initialization of i18next:

```js
...
  interpolation: { format: format },
...
```

I would like the output to be "Bread, that is not bad".
So I hoped that something like:

```json
{
  ...
  "food_is_good_1" : "$t(food,capitalize), that's not bad",
  "food_is_good_2" : "{{$t(food),capitalize}}, that's not bad",
  "food_is_good_3" : "{{food,capitalize}}, that's not bad",
  ...
}
```

would do the trick.
The first option displays errors : `"failed parsing options string in nesting"`
The last two options warn: `missed to pass in variable food,capitalize for interpolating {{food,capitalize}}`

Comment: And what is the code you're using when attempting to get this translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option works in the latest `i18next` (v19).

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-g1d47?file=/src/i18n.js